# Need help using awk or similar to print/output a partial line of a JSON file

Tags: awk, sed, printing, grep, cat

In the following example, I need to readjust the content within the 2nd set of quotes on **line 5**, up to, but not beyond the decimal point.

The contents of the quotes vary so everything between `"` and `.` must be captured and cannot be matched by using a search string based on any contents between.

It is also possible that in the future the line number may change, however, the line can always be found by searching for "Item".

The process should utilize `awk`, `grep`, `cat`, `sed` or a combination of them due to the limitations of the proprietary environment/OS. I have searched around but wasn't able to find anything that would work as desired.

*filename: data.json*

```
{
"Brand": "Marketside",
"Price": "3.97",
"SKU": "48319448",
"Item": "12-ct_Large_Grade_A(Brown_Organic).48319448",
}
```

An Example of a successful output would be:

```
12-ct_Large_Grade_A(Brown_Organic)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to SO. I suggest you to consider parsing JSON first, and then processing your value details will get much easier. Also, please add the approaches you have already tried and a few examples of what are the expected results you look for, so your question is not seen as just a do-me-a-favor job description.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I really have no idea what I'm doing. I have a book on linux and it doesn't give much in the way of examples. I have used cat and grep as well as awk examples, and can print out portions of the page, but can never seem to get the results I'm looking for. I will update the post as good as I can. - Thanks!

Comment: Your example input file looks more of a JSON file than a *randomized text*, do you have a few more lines of examples on how it looks like?

Comment: That is the entire contents of the .json file. Sorry, when I said Randomized, I was referring to the always different value I need to extract ("Item": "value_is_never_the_same_here.or here").

Comment: Mike I think the problem needs to be addressed with more context on available tools, running environment toolset and versions, actual input examples, actual output examples and the actual goal behind the question.

Comment: Your question should remain simply a question. I have rolled back your latest edit with your solution and the commentary. You might still want to review the [how to ask section](/help/how-to-ask) in th [help] before you post new questions.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement to rely exclusively on line-oriented tools to manipulate JSON seems extremely misdirected. When manipulating structured formats, use tools which understand the structured format.

```
jq '.Item|split(".")[0]' data.json
```

to extract up to the first dot; or

```
jq '.Item|sub("[.][^.]*$";"")' data.json
```

to discard the text from the last dot until the end of the field.

(`jq` doesn't like the superfluous last comma after the `Item` in your pseudo-JSON, though.)

There is no doubt in anyone's mind that your *acute* problem *as stated* can be solved with a simple Awk or `sed` script. What happens then - what already happened here - is that you discover *additional* requirements which were not obvious from the toy example you posted. A proper, portable solution copes with JSON samples with strings with embedded commas and escaped double quotes, and continues to work when the superficial JSON format changes because a component somewhere upstream is updated to put all the JSON on a single line or whatever.

Comment: Unfortunately while this comment may be helpful to others, jq is not an option on this proprietary environment/OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk:

```
awk -F'.' '/Item/{split(substr($0,1,L=length($0)-length($NF)-1),a,"\"");print a[4]}'
12.ct.Large.Grade.A(Brown_Organic)
```

It search for `Item`  and then print from `"` to latest `.`

Split the string by `.`
Find the length of latest part after the split `length($NF)`
Extract this lengt from total to find position of latest `.` `length($0)-length($NF)`
Then split the the first part by `"` and print the 4th part.

Comment: But then this fails if the field contains additional dots. The OP commented on a now-deleted answer with an additional requirement (arguably the question should be updated with this information).

Comment: @tripleee Updated to print to latest .

Comment: It is always nice to know why someone give -1...